# how to save a map object as a global variable in appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

what is the most efficient method for saving a Map Object in app script with setting script properties. I have attempted to strigify the map and retrieve it, however it only returns an empty map. I have limited knowledge of app script and javascript and therefore might have made misunderstood some part of the language.

This is my current attempt with only returns an empty map

```
//In open function 
var scriptPrp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
scriptPrp.setProperty('anglishWords', jsonText);

//In function that adds more elements to the map 
//grabbing the json text object and converting it into a map again 
var scriptPrp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var jsonT = scriptPrp.getProperty('anglishWords');
const anglishWordsE = new Map(Object.entries(JSON.parse(jsonT)));
```

This method returns an empty map even if had values in the map that I saved and doesn't change after a set is added to the map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of `PropertiesService`, the string value can be stored. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) So, unfortunately, in the current stage, the Map object cannot be directly stored. If you want to achieve this, it is required to convert the Map object to the string. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
// Prepare a sample Map object.
const sampleMap = new Map([["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"], ["key3", "value3"]]);
console.log(sampleMap.get("key2")); // <--- value2

// Store the Map object as a string to PropertiesService.
const prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
prop.setProperty("sample", JSON.stringify([...sampleMap]));

// Load the Map object from PropertiesService.
const str = prop.getProperty("sample");
const loadedMap = new Map(JSON.parse(str));
console.log(loadedMap.get("key2")); // <--- value2
```

#### Note:

- By the way, there are the limitations in PropertiesService. Please be careful about this. [Ref (Author: me)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/report-specification-of-properties-service-for-google-apps-script-198c487f3896)

#### References:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)
- [Report: Specification of Properties Service for Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/report-specification-of-properties-service-for-google-apps-script-198c487f3896)